# Linked list doesn't function properly

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I'm attempting to extract text from a text file using linked lists. My code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20
struct node
{
    char * str;
    struct node * node;
};
typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node * WordList;
typedef Node * Node_ptr;
void addtext(WordList * lst_ptr);
void report(WordList words);
Node * createnode(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    WordList words = NULL;
    addtext(&words);
    report(words);
    return 0;
}
Node * createnode(char *str)
{
    Node_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Node));
    newnode_ptr -> str = NULL;
    newnode_ptr -> node = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}

void addtext(WordList * lst_ptr)
{
    FILE *fileinput;
    char word[N];
    char *pnt;
    if ((fileinput = fopen("test.txt", "rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file. Please check if the file is in the right directory and you are giving the correct name.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fscanf(fileinput, "%19s", word)  == 1)
    {

        Node * newnode = createnode(word);
        if (*lst_ptr==NULL)
        {
            newnode->node = *lst_ptr;
            *lst_ptr = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *iter;
            for (iter = *lst_ptr; iter -> node != NULL; iter = iter -> node);
            iter -> node = newnode;
        }
        pnt = strtok (word," ");
        while (pnt != NULL)
        {
            newnode->str = pnt;
            pnt = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    fclose(fileinput);

    return ;
}

void report(WordList words)
{
    if (words == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n") ;
        return ;
    }
    printf("%s\n",words -> str);
    report(words -> node);
    return;
}
```

The text file I've made contains the following:

```
Hello
Bye
```

But the output of my program is:

```
Bye
(random characters)
```

Meaning that it prints the last word. My guess is that when I call report it point to the last element of the list and keeps going from there for as many times as the amount of words in the text file.
I also tried a different approach on the report function:

```
void report(WordList words)
{
    Node * iter;
    for (iter = words; iter!=NULL; iter = iter->node)
    {
        printf("%s\n", iter->str);
    }
    return;
}
```

But now it prints \n until the loop ends. Am I missing something simple or am I making a grave mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strtok()` modifies the original string and returns pointers to elements of the original string. In this case the original string is stored in a local array `char word[N];`. The local array will vanish on returning the function `addtext` and refering the array from the function `report` after that is illegal.

To avoid this trouble, you should allocate some new regions and copy the string there. It can be done like this:

```
pnt = strtok (word," ");
while (pnt != NULL)
{
    newnode->str = malloc(strlen(pnt) + 1); /* allocate a region (+1 for terminating null-character) */
    if (newnode->str == NULL) /* check if allocation succeeded */
    {
        /* handle allocation failure */
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(newnode->str, pnt); /* copy the string */
    pnt = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified:

```
newnode->str = strdup(pnt);
```